# Reopen previously closed Window Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I developed a program to learn how log-in works. I've got a window(jFrame) where you can login with a button on it "create new account". If you click this butten, the login window closes and the create acc. window(another file) opens up. I want it to reopen the login window after you've created your acc.

#### My Problem:

---

I don't know how to reopen the login window. Be it by restarting the mainmethod or somethingelse, which you guys can tell me hopefully .

#### First window

```java
public class password extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public password() {
        initComponents();
    }
     private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        [some more Elements...]

        jButton1.setText("Create an account");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        [more layoutstuff...]
      }
     //event where it opens the new window and closes the login window  
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        register reg = new register();
        reg.register();
        dispose();
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(password.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(password.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(password.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(password.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new password().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
     // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
      [more elements...]
}
```

second window

```java
public class register extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public register() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        [again more elements and layoutstuff...]
    }
   public static void register() {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new register().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    [more elements]
}
```

Please excuse me for my question but I am very new to programming.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should always include some code that you've done so that we can help you. So far, we don't know how you're opening/closing the first window so it's difficult to understand your issue.

Comment: JFrame is the main frame of SWING and you cannot "dispose" it whenever you want. I believe you confuse JDialog with JFrame.

Comment: Don't use the Login window as your application start class. Use the main application as your startup class and hide it (don't make it visible). Open the login form: `new password().setVisible(true);`. Don't close (dispose) the login JFrame (hide it instead) until login is ultimately complete and successful, even during registration. The **JDialog** is better suited for these satellite forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just hide and then show the login window later or you could roll up a new login window.